# How can I "type" in a keyboard layout other than the ones I have configured?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm working on a Cinnamon desktop environment on a GNU/Linux system (Devuan Chimaera to be specific). I want to do some typing in a foreign language. My keyboard doesn't have this layout; and I don't want my desktop environment to have it, since I don't really know which key does what.

I tried using on-screen keyboards:

- The one you get with `dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.Cinnamon /org/Cinnamon org.Cinnamon.ToggleKeyboard`
- onboard (which seems to be associated with MATE)

but neither of these offered to switch to arbitrary keyboard layouts.

What should I do?

, like the one that's available as "Virtual Keyboard" on my

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're better off using a character map utility, like [gucharmap](http://gucharmap.sourceforge.net/); it's not laid out like a keyboard, but - you don't know how your foreign language's associated keyboard layout even works, so this might actually be easier.